Backward(inputs=) doesn’t work when the model is moved between devices
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weight_mul = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(D,))
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(D,))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x * self.temp_weight
        return x

D = 5

x = torch.randn(D,).cuda()
model = Model()
model.cuda()
model.temp_weight = model.weight * model.weight_mul
model.cpu(); model.cuda()
output = model(x)
output.sum().backward(inputs=[model.weight, model.weight_mul])

print(model.weight.grad)
print(model.weight_mul.grad)

To my surprise, the .grad are None. There are two ways to get the backward() to work. One is to remove the inputs to backward(), the other is to remove model.cpu(); model.cuda(). But why?

I think this happens because you're moving tensors around without updating the autograd engine.
Consider this example:
D = 5
x = torch.ones((D,), device="cuda")
a = 2 * torch.ones((D,), device="cuda", requires_grad=True)
q = a # keep a reference to a
b = 3 * torch.ones((D,), device="cuda", requires_grad=True)
y = a*x + b
s = y.sum()


a = a.cpu()
a = a.cuda()

s.backward(inputs=[a])
print(a.grad) # --> None
s.backward(inputs=[q])
print(a.grad) # --> None
print(q.grad) # --> tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], device='cuda:0')


So, when you write a = a.cpu() or a = a.cuda(), you get a copy of a when a move to different device memory occurs. However, the underlying graph for back-propagation is not automatically updated to reflect the new address of the tensor in the new memory type. You can see that this is true because computing the gradient with respect to q, which refers to the original location of a works as expected.
In your case, when you call model.cpu() or model.cuda(), the same will happen to alll nn.Parameter objects that are attributes of model. Since self.temp_weight is not updated to reflect the new location of model.weight, autograd behaves unexpectedly.
However, note that this is just a part of the full picture, because if you try to save a reference to a nn.Parameter in model, like
q = model.weight

it doesn't work. So clearly, there's something else going on in addition to the logic I've outlined above.
EDIT:
Wrapping self.temp_weight in a nn.Parameter is enough to solve this:
model.temp_weight = nn.Parameter(model.weight * model.weight_mul)

EDIT2:
Wrapping in nn.Module:
class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModule, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, w1, w2):
        return w1 * w2


class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weight_mul = nn.Parameter(2*torch.ones(D,), requires_grad=True)
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(3*torch.ones(D,), requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x * self.temp_weight(self.weight, self.weight_mul)
        return x

model.temp_weight = MyModule()


I suspected the same thing. In your example, the issue would go away if you changed the moving of a to a_cpu = a.cpu(); a_gpu = a_cpu.cuda(). Now a refers to the correct leaf node. With the moving of a model being in-place, how would you go about doing something similar?

Yes, the issue would go away. I'd wrap an nn.Module around temp_weight. Please see an edit to my answer

It doesn't for me. With nn.Parameter or register_parameter, even backward() doesn't work.

Right. My bad. Printed the wrong value... Is wrapping this in nn.Module acceptable for you? See another edit.

But also, may I ask what's the purpose of this unconventional usage?
